# Replace the string '1 year' with '1' in the dataset

Tags: python

I have a dataset where I need to replace some string values with another set of string values. In this case, I want to replace the string "1 year" with "1". I have used the code-

```
loan_data['emp_length_int']=loan_data['emp_length'].str.replace("1 year","1")
```

and then use the unique function to check if the values have changed but to no avail-

```
array(['10+  ', '0', '1 year', '3  ', '8  ', '9  ', '4  ', '5  ', '6  ','2 ', '7  ', nan], dtype=object)
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does `.str.` do? Doesn't it cause an error?

Comment: `string.replace("1 Year", "1")` is how you need to use, not sure how you are able to use `something.str.replace("1 year","1")`  it must throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what tpye of dataset/array you are using. Assuming that its a np.array; and that loan_data['emp_length_int'] returns the array

```
array(['10+ ', '0', '1 year', '3 ', '8 ', '9 ', '4 ', '5 ', '6 ', '2 ', '7 ', nan], dtype=object)

for i in range(len(loan_data['emp_length_int'])):
    loan_data['emp_length_int'][i] = loan_data['emp_length_int'][i].replace('1 year','1')
```

should do the trick.

What you did would only replace "1 year" with "1" if and only if loan_data['emp_length'] = '1 year'

It wouldnt work on the array as the array is an array. Not a string. str.replace() only does it on strings. Please check the docs on your array type as well as the replace() function.

> https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html